# MFA Usage REST API in OneLogin

Tags: onelogin

In OneLogin, is there any example of retrieving all users (maybe filtered by a query and paginated) to determine their MFA enrollment/usage status from a REST or any other programmatic API?

I have been checking here: https://developers.onelogin.com/api-docs/1/getting-started/dev-overview

But I am new to OneLogin and would like to know how this is typically achieved.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this API to get User's enrolled MFA Factors:
https://api-domain/api/1/users/user-id/otp_devices

Please note that This API only returns factors that are enrolled and can be verified via API. Currently OneLogin supports only OneLogin SMS, OneLogin Voice and OTP Authenticators via API.

Let me know if that helps.

Comment: Thanks Mayur. It would be helpful to have an endpoint that gives the enrolled factors for all users (maybe filtered, list or query-based) in a single API. Having this being called for every user is turning out to be cumbersome.

Comment: Why would you need it for all users? If it needs for reporting then I think you can get them from Reports.

Comment: Yes, agree. But I need programmatic access to the API which gives this info for all users. Reports would be UI based. Even if there was an approach to pull the reports data ...

Comment: Currently, I don't believe OneLogin supports this. And even future it is unlikely they will provide this. Maybe you can programmatically check events and then build required report using these events. Hope this helps.